# I use python openpyxl for working with for loop in excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, loops, openpyxl

Ihave data that has a special structure. The data is grouped as shown at the screenshot.
[Data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF2hU.png)

Using python, I determined the data outline levels, and I want to set this information about the levels in the cells for each row, in a new column, for example, column=8.
I use code

```
import openpyxl as opx

wb=opx.load_workbook('./sources/example.xlsx')
print(wb.sheetnames)
ws=wb.active
print(ws.max_row)

for row_index, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(min_col=2, min_row=2, max_col=ws.max_column+1, max_row=ws.max_row+1)):
    ws.cell(row=row_index,column=8).value=ws.row_dimensions[row_index].outline_level
    print(row_index, ws.row_dimensions[row_index].outline_level)

 wb.save('./sources/test.xlsx')
```

But I get traceback

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lisit/PycharmProjects/File_parsing/test_loop.py", line 11, in 
    ws.cell(row=row_index,column=8).value=ws.row_dimensions[row_index].outline_level
  File "C:\Users\lisit\Python\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 236, in cell
    raise ValueError("Row or column values must be at least 1")
ValueError: Row or column values must be at least 1

Can you please help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue**

row_index starts at 0 (enumerate default behavior)

```
for row_index, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(min_col=2, min_row=2, max_col=ws.max_column+1, max_row=ws.max_row+1)):
```

**Two Options to fix**

Either: Use row_index + 1

```
ws.cell(row=row_index+1,column=8).value=ws.row_dimensions[row_index+1].outline_level
```

Or, set default start parameter to 1, i.e. enumerate(..., start = 1)

```
for row_index, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(min_col=2, min_row=2, max_col=ws.max_column+1, max_row=ws.max_row+1), start = 1):
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast help.
The first variant I tried earlier and the values were stored in cells with displacement, that why I published this question. 
But the second variant helped me. Now it works. Thank you very much.